# Error: Could not find or load main class com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.multilang.MultiLangDaemon

Tags: amazon-kcl

what's the problem??
i follow this tutorial to run the amazon kinesis.
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-python

i follow until the last step, that will give me the command line.this is my command line

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe -cp C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\amazon-kinesis-client-1.6.1.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch-1.10.20.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.20.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.20.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\aws-java-sdk-kinesis-1.10.20.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.20.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.20.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\commons-codec-1.6.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\commons-lang-2.6.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\guava-18.0.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\httpclient-4.3.6.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\httpcore-4.3.3.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\jackson-core-2.5.3.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\jackson-databind-2.5.3.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\joda-time-2.8.1.jar:C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\amazon_kclpy-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\amazon_kclpy\jars\protobuf-java-2.6.1.jar:D:\python_Project\amazon_kclpy\samples com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.multilang.MultiLangDaemon sample.properties
```

i using python 2.7.11 for the code and windows 8.1. for the command i use to generate the command line:
    python samples\amazon_kclpy_helper.py --print_com
mand --java "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe" --properties sample
s\sample.properties

did i miss something?

Answer (score 2):

I too encountered this error and solved it.

Actually, the helper script generates command for UNIX system. jars in classpath are separated by colons and for windows it has to be semi-colon.

So, in `amazon_kclpy_helper.py` change `return ':'.join(...` to `return ';'.join(...`. There are two places that you need to change.

Also in `sample.properties` file set `executableName = python your_kclpy_app.py`

Hope this helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on amazon EC2. It was fixed by upgrading java from 1.7 to 1.8.

**Linux** 
sudo yum install java-1.8.0
sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk

**Windows**
Download and install JDK 1.8.0 (Java SE 1.8)
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

Hope it helps